# Scala proper using of Try and Option combined together

Tags: scala

I'm using `Try()` to wrap calls to not-100%-reliable 3-rd party service which return `Option()` of some type therefore receiving `Some(DataDto)` or `None`.

So it looks something like this:

```
private def fetchData(): Option(DataDto) {
    val data: Try[Option[DataDto]] = Try(problematicService.getMeStuff())

    data match {
        case Success(maybeDataDto) => {
            maybeDataDto match {
                case Some(dataDto) => Some(dataDto)
                case None => None
            }
       }
       case Failure(_) => None
    }
}
```

What is the best way to implement such behavior? I feel that this implementation is to verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a `Try` to an `Option` and `flatten` it.

```
Try(s.getMeStuff()).toOption.flatten
```