# Convert Seq[Try[Option(String, Any)]] into Try[Option[Map[String, Any]]]

Tags: scala

How to conveniently convert Seq[Try[Option[String, Any]]] into Try[Option[Map[String, Any]]].

If any Try before convert throws an exception, the converted Try should throw as well.

Comment: I don't think `Option[String,Any]` makes sense.  [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) takes a single type parameter.  Did you mean `Option[(String,Any)]` ?

Comment: I don't get the point of `Try[Option[SOMETHING]]`. Option is either `None` or `Some` meaning invalid values have been taken care of by the time they reach `Try`. It seems a bit redundant.

Comment: @jrook There is scenario you want to keep track if an operation is Success or Fail, and even this operation is successful, it can return a None or Some.

Comment: @texasbruce If I am controlling the signature and get `None` from an operation, I already know something bad happened. If I wanted to know the reason why that happened, then I would directly `Try` the operation. The case in which an operation yields None without any error seems dubious to me. Why would I want a logic that can produce `None` as a normal value? I would appreciate if you could show me a real-world use case.

Comment: @jrook There are many cases, such as, when you query a record from db. You use Try to indicate whether there's something wrong with db or connection. Then use Some or None to indicate whether the record exists.

Comment: @texasbruce I would still not wrap these inside each other and instead use [toOption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027503/scala-proper-using-of-try-and-option-combined-together). But I get the idea. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input type has a tuple inside the `Option` then this should give you the result you want:

```
val in: Seq[Try[Option[(String, Any)]]] = ???

val out: Try[Option[Map[String,Any]]] = Try(Some(in.flatMap(_.get).toMap))
```

If any of the `Try`s is `Failure` then the outer `Try` will catch the exception raised by the `get` and return `Failure`

The `Some` is there to give the correct return type

The `get` extracts the `Option` from the `Try` (or raises an exception)

Using `flatMap` rather than `map` removes the `Option` wrapper, keeping all `Some` values and discaring `None` values, giving `Seq[(String, Any)]`

The `toMap` call converts the `Seq` to a `Map`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that's not very clean but may help get you started.  It assumes `Option[(String,Any)]`, returns the first `Failure` if there are any in the input `Seq` and just drops `None` elements.

**foo.scala**

```scala
package foo
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}

object foo {
  val x0 = Seq[Try[Option[(String, Any)]]]()
  val x1 = Seq[Try[Option[(String, Any)]]](Success(Some(("A",1))), Success(None))
  val x2 = Seq[Try[Option[(String, Any)]]](Success(Some(("A",1))), Success(Some(("B","two"))))
  val x3 = Seq[Try[Option[(String, Any)]]](Success(Some(("A",1))), Success(Some(("B","two"))), Failure(new Exception("bad")))
  def f(x: Seq[Try[Option[(String, Any)]]]) =
    x.find( _.isFailure ).getOrElse( Success(Some(x.map( _.get ).filterNot( _.isEmpty ).map( _.get ).toMap)) )
}
```

Example session

```
bash-3.2$ scalac foo.scala
bash-3.2$ scala -classpath .
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import foo.foo._
import foo.foo._

scala> f(x0)
res0: scala.util.Try[Option[Equals]] = Success(Some(Map()))

scala> f(x1)
res1: scala.util.Try[Option[Equals]] = Success(Some(Map(A -> 1)))

scala> f(x2)
res2: scala.util.Try[Option[Equals]] = Success(Some(Map(A -> 1, B -> two)))

scala> f(x3)
res3: scala.util.Try[Option[Equals]] = Failure(java.lang.Exception: bad)

scala> :quit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a functional support library like [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) then there are two tricks that can help this along:

1. Many things like `List` and `Try` are [traversable](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html), which means that (if Cats's implicits are in scope) they have a `sequence` method that can swap two types, for example converting `List[Try[T]]` to `Try[List[T]]` (failing if any of the items in the list are failure).
2. Almost all of the container types support a `map` method that can operate on the contents of a container, so if you have a function from `A` to `B` then `map` can convert a `Try[A]` to a `Try[B]`.  (In Cats language they are [functors](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/functor.html) but the container-like types in the standard library generally have `map` already.)

[Cats doesn't directly support `Seq`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1222), so this answer is mostly in terms of `List` instead.

Given that type signature, you can iteratively `sequence` the item you have to in effect push the list type down one level in the type chain, then `map` over that container to work on its contents.  That can look like:

```
import cats.implicits._
import scala.util._

def convert(listTryOptionPair: List[Try[Option[(String, Any)]]]): Try[
  Option[Map[String, Any]]
] = {
  val tryListOptionPair = listTryOptionPair.sequence
  tryListOptionPair.map { listOptionPair =>
    val optionListPair = listOptionPair.sequence
    optionListPair.map { listPair =>
      Map.from(listPair)
    }
  }
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xbQ8ZbkoRSCXGDJX0PgJAQ has a slightly more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is by using a `foldLeft`:

```scala
// Let's say this is the object you're trying to convert
val seq: Seq[Try[Option[(String, Any)]]] = ???

seq.foldLeft(Try(Option(Map.empty[String, Any]))) {
  case (acc, e) =>
    for {
      accOption  <- acc
      elemOption <- e
    } yield elemOption match {
      case Some(value) => accOption.map(_ + value)
      case None        => accOption
    }
}
```

You start off with en empty Map. You then use a for comprehension to go through the current map and element and finally you add a new tuple in the map if present.

Answer (score -1):

The following solutions is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897950/2928853) to the point that *almost* makes the question a duplicate.

Method 1: Using recursion

```
def trySeqToMap1[X,Y](trySeq : Seq[Try[Option[(X, Y)]]]) : Try[Option[Map[X,Y]]] = {

  def helper(it : Iterator[Try[Option[(X,Y)]]], m : Map[X,Y] = Map()) : Try[Option[Map[X,Y]]] = {
    if(it.hasNext) {
      val x = it.next()
      if(x.isFailure)
        Failure(x.failed.get)
      else if(x.get.isDefined)
        helper(it, m + (x.get.get._1-> x.get.get._2))
      else
        helper(it, m)
    } else Success(Some(m))
  }

  helper(trySeq.iterator)
}
```

Method 2: directly pattern matching in case you are able to get a stream or a `List` instead:

```
  def trySeqToMap2[X,Y](trySeq : LazyList[Try[Option[(X, Y)]]], m : Map[X,Y]= Map.empty[X,Y]) : Try[Option[Map[X,Y]]] =
    trySeq match {
      case Success(Some(h)) #:: tail => trySeqToMap2(tail, m + (h._1 -> h._2))
      case Success(None) #:: tail => tail => trySeqToMap2(tail, m)
      case Failure(f) #:: _ => Failure(f)
      case _ => Success(Some(m))
    }
```

*note*: this answer was previously using different method signatures. It has been updated to conform to the signature given in the question.